# Laravel 4 Mongodb (jenssegers' driver) storing tags as array of strings - without indexes

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

If anyone have more experience using Jens Seger's Laravel Mongo Package (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) please help me out.

I have jenssegers mongodb 'eloquent' model  **Performer**, I want my document to look something like this (simplified, some unrelated fields removed)

```
{
  "performer" : "Bruno Mars", 
  "search_terms" : ["bruno mars", "pop singer", "bruno"]
}
```

When I insert this in Mongo command line, it looks exactly as that! Perfect.

But when i do this in my controller:

```
$tags = ["bruno mars", "pop singer", "bruno"];
$performer = new Performer; //via Moloquent (Jens extension)
$performer->performer = "Bruno Mars";
$performer->search_terms = $tags;
$performer->save();
```

I get document that looks like this:

```
{
  "performer" : "Bruno Mars", 
  "search_terms" : {"0" : "bruno mars", "1" : "pop singer", "2" : "bruno"}
}
```

Why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong with php array? Should I just create a string "array" like

```
$searchTermsAsString = "['Bruno Mars', 'pop singer']";
```

?

My model looks like this:

```
class Performer extends Moloquent
{
    protected $collection = "search_terms";
    protected $database =  'tb_dev';
     protected $connection = 'mongodb2';
    //THIS IS GHETTO FIX
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 
}
```

I am also new to Mongodb, so I might be delusional thinking that

['item','item2','item3'] is different from {'1' : "item", '2' : "item2", '3' : "item3"}

Which if I understand correctly one is ARRAY another one is OBJECT (As it is in Javascript and json)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out why this was happening...and it had nothing to do with either model or mongo

I ran through the loop adding various tags, and at the end of the loop I ran `array_unique();` to remove duplicate tags.

APPARENTLY if you `array_push('item');` and that **'item'** already exist in array, it will create numeric indexes as such: `array(0 => 'item1', 1 => 'item', 2=>'item')...` of course, solution was simpler than I thought.

Thanks.